# Creating table with the help of for loop function

Tags: r

I am trying to design `for loop` which will return differences of 2nd and 3rd rows of my tables, but for loop keeps returning very large table or NAs whatever I do. How can I modify my for loop? Like final result will return the same result as  `cbind(a.trade, b.trade, c.trade, d.trade, f.trade, g.trade, h.trade, l.trade, m.trade, n.trade, r.trade)`. Thank you

```
a<- read.csv("2003.csv", header=TRUE)
b<- read.csv("2004.csv", header=TRUE, na.strings='             -')
c<- read.csv("2005.csv", header=TRUE)
d<- read.csv("2006.csv", header=TRUE)
f<- read.csv("2007.csv", header=TRUE)
g<- read.csv("2008.csv", header=TRUE)
h<- read.csv("2009.csv", header=TRUE)
l<- read.csv("2010.csv", header=TRUE)
m<- read.csv("2011.csv", header=TRUE)
n<- read.csv("2012.csv", header=TRUE)
r<- read.csv("2013.csv", header=TRUE)

a.trade <- a$Exports- a$General.Imports
b.trade <- b$Exports- b$General.Imports
c.trade <- c$Exports- c$General.Imports
d.trade <- d$Exports- d$General.Imports
f.trade <- f$Exports- f$General.Imports
g.trade <- g$Exports- g$General.Imports
h.trade <- h$Exports- h$General.Imports
l.trade <- l$Exports- l$General.Imports
m.trade <- m$Exports- m$General.Imports
n.trade <- n$Exports- n$General.Imports
r.trade <- r$Exports- r$General.Imports
cbind(a.trade, b.trade, c.trade, d.trade, f.trade,
 g.trade, h.trade, l.trade, m.trade, n.trade, r.trade)


for (i in 2:55, i+5) {
x<-c(a,b,c,d,f,g,h,l,m,n,r)
v<-cbind(x[[i+1]]-x[[i+2]])
print(v)
}
```

Comment: It may be better to read all the files in a `list` and the do the transformation. i.e. `files <- list.files('\\d+.csv'); trade <- sapply(files, function(x) { dat <- read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE); with(dat, Exports-General.Imports)})`

Comment: Read about `apply` family, `list.files` function and list variables.

Comment: but list files function returns character(0). I dont know how I can solve that.

Comment: I think you need `files <- list.files(pattern='\\d+.csv')`  assuming that all the files are in the working directory.

Comment: `for (i in 2:55, i+5)` is not valid R code.  You are thinking of a different language at the other end of the alphabet

Answer (score 0):

```
data_frame(year = 2003:2013) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    do("%s.csv" %>%
        sprintf(.$year) %>%
        read.csv) %>%
    mutate(trade = Exports - Imports) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarize(difference = trade[3] - trade[2])
```